# how to check if a file format existing in a particluar folder using shell

Tags: shell

I want to use a if condition to delete records from the table.
eg :
if ()
then
     delete from tablename where filecode like '%A%';
     commit;
end if;

the if condition is to check or a particular file format 
so there is a possibility of 3 file formats say (A.csv,B.CSV,C.CSV)to arrive in the /a/b/input directory 
the column filcode in the table will hold the filename from where the record is obtained.

The above script will run in the location /a/b/scripts directory

Comment: Provide more context. What do you mean by file format?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f /a/b/input ]; then
   sh /a/b/scripts/your-script
fi
```

or this:

```
test -f /a/b/input && sh /a/b/scripts/your-script
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you simply want is a script like this. It checks if a given file exists.

```
#!/bin/sh
file=$1
if [ -e "$file" ]; then
    echo "File $file exists."
fi
```

Or simply

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -e "$1" ] && echo "File $1 exists."
```

Save the script in UNIX format in `/a/b/scripts` like `/a/b/scripts/check_file_exists.sh`, and run:

```
sh /a/b/scripts/check_file_exists.sh /a/b/input/somefile.ext
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I have tried using grep and find commands, but all futile
hi.. i think i have nt elaborated my question properly.
I  have a script to truncate few recorcds in a table based on the file format.
Suppose if a fileformat A.CSV comes in the folder /a/b/input , I want to delete the previous existing records in the table which belows to the fileformat A.CSV.
This script will run in the location /a/b/scripts.

Comment: @S.MohanaPriya Please give all the details.

Comment: What more info should i provide ?
ask me your questions , i ll fill in your answers as nothing strikes my mind now.

Comment: What table and records do you refer to? Can you elaborate what you mean about `I want to delete the previous existing records in the table which belows to the fileformat A.CSV`?

Comment: Example input and expected outputs would give more clarity to your question. You can add it to your question by editing it.

Comment: i have edited my question , can u please check it now

Answer (score 0):

The unix program to check for file formats is called `file`.  To see all the file formats (listed as mime-types) in the directory `/a/b/input`, run:

```
file -L --mime-type /a/b/input/*
```

If you want to select only the files in that directory that are have the jpeg file format, run:

```
file -L --mime-type /a/b/input/* | grep 'image/jpeg'
```